# TextColor is changing to wrong one

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm just trying to change textcolor in my recyclerview using this code ↓↓↓

```
itemView.resultTV.textColor = if (result >= 0) R.color.green else R.color.red
```

But it changes the color to light purple, which is neither basic color nor green nor red.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the `resId` of the color, while `setTextColor` expects the `Color` . You should use Resources to convert the R.color to color the resource `represents`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code-

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green)

ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

setTextColor expects "int" of Color which we can provide by **R.color."*color code*"** rather than resId.